# PHP JSON Error when using Basic Authentication

Tags: php, json, basic-authentication

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to send a JSON request via basic authentication. The server responds with this error:

```
 object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) {  
 ["code"]=> int(-32600) ["message"]=> string(44) "expected content type 
 to be application/json" } ["jsonrpc"]=> string(3) "2.0" }
```

From the API documentation, here is the request format:

```
  Request Format:

  {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "id":1,
       "method": "acct.name.get",
       "params": [
             "QrOxxEE9-fATtgAD" ]
  }
```

Here is the code...Any help would be great - thanks

```
 <?php

 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";

 $request = [
    'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
    'id' => 1,
    'method' => 'acct.name.get',
    'params' =>['CA6ph0n7EicnDADS'],
 ];

 $curl_post_data = json_encode($request);

 $service_url = 'https://userapi.voicestar.com/api/jsonrpc/1';
 $curl = curl_init($service_url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  "username:password");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
 $response = json_decode($curl_response);
 curl_close($curl);

 var_dump($response);

?>
```

Comment: Why are you reducing/reindexing your array with `$out = array_values($request);`?  Even with the right headers, I don't see this request working correctly.

Comment: Quite honestly, I'm a complete newbee - I'm actually trying to retrieve data from the API (a GET instead of POST-ing?) - I'm trying different things to figure things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's the small things... your JSON/Array is malformed. an extra comma at the end of params might actually be the problem. try the following.

Malformed arrays will cause json_encode to return a null.

```
 <?php

 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";

 $request = [
    'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
    'id'      => 1,
    'method'  => 'acct.name.get',
    'params'  => ['CA6ph0n7EicnDADS']
 ];

 $curl_post_data = json_encode($request);

 $headers = ['Content-type: application/json'];


 $service_url = 'https://userapi.voicestar.com/api/jsonrpc/1';
 $curl = curl_init($service_url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  "username:password");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
 $response = json_decode($curl_response);
 curl_close($curl);

 var_dump($response);

?>
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Awesome. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the API is looking for the request header to reflect JSON.

try adding the following to your options and see what is returned

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
```

Comment: json_encode can take arrays. Associative arrays will be converted to the proper name:value pair....

Convert 
 $curl_post_data = json_encode($out);
to 
 $curl_post_data = json_encode($request);

and see what is returned

Comment: The same thing - object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["code"]=> int(-32600) ["message"]=> string(44) "expected content type to be application/json" } ["jsonrpc"]=> string(3) "2.0" }

Comment: I am trying to get information from the API - Do I POST the JSON (request) - or is there a "CURLOPT_GET" option?

Comment: I see CURLOPT_GET does not exist - http://www.hacksparrow.com/php-curlopt_get-does-not-exist.html

Comment: Thinking about it. sending json in the postfields option doesn't make any sense. they have to be name=value&name=value syntax. 

Try converting `$curl_post_data = json_encode($out);`  to `$curl_post_data = http_build_query($request);`

That seems to make more sense to me on how this API would be expecting data. Though it wouldn't make any sense with the API response error saying it was expecting json.

Comment: Also, to request using the GET method, you append the query_string at the end of the url.

Example: `http://api.example.com/page.php?name=value&name2=value...`

Comment: From the API documentation, here is what they give as the JSON format: Request

{
 "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 "id":1,
 "method": "acct.name.get",
 "params": [
  "QrOxxEE9-fATtgAD" ]
}